# Is it true that $p\lim(E(x_n))=E(p\lim(x_n))$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am conjecturing that 
$$p\lim(E(x_n))=E(p\lim(x_n))$$
I tried to prove it using the delta-epsilon definitions, but it became very messy, and I couldn't do it.

How do we prove this?

Comment: You should need to assume that the sequence is bounded so you can apply dominated convergence. This then follows since a sequence converges in probability iff every subsequence has a subsubsequence that converges almost surely. I suspect this may have been asked here before, though.

Comment: The first question to ask is whether the $x_n$ are integrable. The second question to ask is what the expression "$\lim(x_n)$" means - are we assuming that the sequence of random variables converges almost surely?

Comment: no, it says plim, limit in probability. though latex doesn't have plim as an option so instead it looks like its multiplying $p$ by $\lim$

Comment: The sequence $\{E(x_n)\}$ is not random, so if it converges in probability it converges in the usual sense. So this question is really "if $x_n\to x$ in probability, then do we have $E(x_n)\to E(x)$?". If you have seen any limit theorems at all, you should know the answer is "not always, but under modest conditions then yes".